# Find duplicates lines based on some delimited fileds on line

Tags: duplicates, field, ksh, partial, lines

I have a file with lines having some fields delimited by "|".

I have to extract the lines that are identical based on some of the fileds
(i.e. find lines which contain the same values for fields 1,2,3 12,and 13)
Other fields contents have no importance for searching but the whole extracted lines have to be complete.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that in KSH scripting 
(By exemple a script with some arguments (order dependent) that define the fileds separator and the fields which have to be compared to find duplicates lines in input file )

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Oli

Comment: It helps if you show what you have for a script so far and some example data. Also, do you want to discard (not print) the lines that have no duplicates and print all lines that are duplicates? Or do you want to print only lines that match one set of criteria?

Answer (score 2):

This prints duplicate lines based on matching fields. It uses an associative array which could grow large depending on the nature of your input file. The output is not sorted so most duplicates are not grouped together (except the first two of a set).

```
awk -F'|' '{ idx=$1$2$3$12$13; if (array[idx] == 1) {print} else if (array[idx]) {print array[idx]; print; array[idx]=1} else {array[idx]=$0}}' inputfile.txt
```

You could probably build up your index list in a shell variable in a wrapper script something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for arg
do
    case arg in    # validate input (could be better)
        +([0-9]) ) # integers only
            idx="$idx'$'$arg"
            ;;
        * )
            echo "Invalid field specifier"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done
awk -F'|' '{ idx='$idx'; if (array ...
```

You can sort the output by piping it through a command such as this:

```
awk ... | sort  --field-separator='|' --key=1,1 --key=2,2 --key=3,3 --key=12,12 --key=13,13
```

Answer (score -1):

This prints lines which are duplicated - just one line each:

```
awk -F'|' '!arr[$1$2$3$12$13]++' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: This is a variation on a different SO question/answer: [Grep only one of partial duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929071/grep-only-one-of-partial-duplicates). Its behaviour is indeed to weed out duplicates, but that means in this context: leaving *both* the original of any duplicate; and *also* leaving any line that doesn't have a duplicate. So the outputfile will contain a lot of false positives.